# How to display texture on the screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

I have a unity scene. I try to display a texture that changes dynamically.

I draw some shape on this texture. How can I do it?

If I use `onGUI` and  `Graphics.DrawTexture` method, it works too slow on mobile platform.

Comment: note, NEVER, EVER use "ongui" (2016).  It is deprecated and does not work. (Just use the UI system for your buttons, etc.)  You basically use SetPixel to "paint" on textures; google for 1000s of examples. Please search first before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D looking for setPixels example to paint with texture in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291826/unity3d-looking-for-setpixels-example-to-paint-with-texture-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Use a canvas with an Image attached to it
You can apply a texture through there.
The OnGUI method is deprecated, try not to use it.